# Potential energy of a spherically symmetric charge density in a spherically symmetric electrostatic potential

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, potential, integration, plasma-physics

I'm interested in calculating the potential energy of a spherically symmetric charge density in a spherically symmetric electrostatic potential. More specific, I'm currently trying to calculate the potential energy of a Debye-distributed charge distribution (but displaced!)

$$
\rho(\vec{r})\propto \frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}\exp^{-\frac{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}{\lambda_{d1}}}
$$

in either a potential of a point charge or again a Debye potential

$$
\Phi(r)\propto 1/r \;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;\Phi(r)\propto \frac{1}{r}\exp^{-r/\lambda_{d2}} \;.
$$
Note that the charge distribution is allowed to be displaced. Physically I'm looking at two simplified atomic shells from different atoms (projectile-target) interacting.

In principal this can be done with the integral
$$
W = \frac{1}{2}\int\rho\Phi dV \; ,
$$

I'm basically at a loss how to simplify the integral. More or less the best I got was something like (exact position of $\rho$ doesn't matter, only distance, so put on z-axis $\vec{r}'=z'\vec{e}_z$; do $\varphi$ integration)

$$
W = \frac{2\pi}{2}\int \rho(|r\vec{e}_r-z'\vec{e}_z|)\Phi(r)r^2\sin{\theta}\, drd\theta \; .
$$

I can't remember of figure out how to simplify the $r\vec{e}_r-z'\vec{e}_z$-stuff more than just a few simple steps or useless substitution. I guess there are some typical "tricks" for those kind of (Green-function-like) integrals which I'm obviously missing.

Comment: What do you mean by "the charge distribution is allowed to be displaced" ?

Comment: Edited my original post. Charge distribution and potential don't have the same origin, i.e. are spherically symmetric around a different point.

Comment: Can't you use the fact that the field of a spherical shell is the same as of a point charge at its centre?

Comment: No, because it's not a point charge interacting with a potential (then it would work like you implied), but two potentials (or a charge distribution with a potential) with each other... I know that for the general case the problem can not be treated analytically, but at least for Debye potentials I was hoping there was a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually integrated this a while ago, I thought I should share the result. It turned out rather simple with the right substitution.

By the way I'm talking about both potential and charge disrtibution as a Debye-like. Point charge is straight forward...

First we put the center of the charge density on the z-axis as mentioned in my question. I get

$$ 
\vec{r}'=z'\vec{e}_z
$$
$$
|r\vec{e}_r-z'\vec{e}_z|^2 = (r\cos\varphi\sin\theta)^2+(r\sin\varphi\sin\theta)^2+(r\cos\theta-z')^2=r^2-2rz'\cos\theta+z'^2\,.
$$

Then I substitute
$$
u^2=r^2-2rz'\cos\theta+z'^2
$$
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}u=\frac{rz'\sin\theta}{u}
$$

$$
I=\int \rho(|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|)\Phi(r)dV = 2\pi\int_0^\infty\left(\int_{u(0)}^{u(\pi)}\frac{ru}{z'}\rho(u)\Phi(r)\,du\right)dr
$$
$$
u(0)^2=r^2-z'^2\;\;\;\;\;u(\pi)^2=r^2+z'^2
$$

One has to watch out for the correct signs because of the squares after that.
Integration $du$ and $dr$ and some simplification and replacing back $z'=r'$ because of symmetry yields

$$
I=\frac{4\pi}{r'}\frac{(e^{-r'/\lambda_{d1}}-e^{-r'/\lambda_{d2}})\lambda_{d1}^2\lambda_{d2}^2}{(\lambda_{d1}^2-\lambda_{d2}^2)} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

> I'm basically at a loss how to simplify the integral.

I am not sure this needs to be done.  In spherically symmetric cases, the volume element, $dV$ is quite simple to deal with.  In your case, you have:
$$
\begin{align}
W & = \frac{1}{2} \int dV \ \rho\left(r\right) \ \Phi\left(r\right) \\
& = \frac{4 \pi \ C}{2} \int dr \ r^{2} \left( r^{-2} e^{-r/\lambda_{D}} \right) \left( r^{-1} e^{-r/\lambda_{D}} \right) \\
& = \frac{4 \pi \ C}{2} \int dr \ \left( r^{-1} e^{-2 r/\lambda_{D}} \right)
\end{align}
$$
where $C$ is some constant.  The direct solution to the integral is the [exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html), $Ei(z)$, given by:
$$
Ei\left(z\right) = - \int_{-z}^{\infty} dt \ \frac{e^{-t}}{t}
$$
which can be solved numerically quite easily.  If you want an analytical approach, you can use the [Laplace transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html) after [integration by parts](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegrationbyParts.html).  To do this, start by getting rid of the annoying extra terms by substituting $r \rightarrow \lambda_{D} x/2$, then integrate by parts to get:
$$
C \int dx \ x^{-1} \ e^{-x} = C\left( e^{-x} \ln{x} + \int dx \ e^{-x} \ln{x} \right)
$$

Now we can use the Laplace transform on the 2nd term on the right-hand side to get:
$$
\mathcal{L} \int dx \ e^{-x} \ln{x} = -\frac{ \ln\lvert{1 + s}\rvert }{ s } + \frac{ \gamma + \ln\lvert{1 + s}\rvert }{ 1 + s }
$$
where $s$ is the transform variable and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).

Note the numerical integral above is valid for arbitrary values of $z$ but the analytical result below is probably limited in its range of validity.  I am sure some of my more mathematically inclined peers could explain in more detail.

Comment: I think I didn't make it clear enough that while both the charge density and the potential are spherically symmetric, they don't have the same origin...